# Галерея flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, слайдер

Есть резиновая галерея, проблема в том, что ширина каждого из ее элементов определилась как изначальная ширина соответствующего изображения. Соответственно при уменьшении экрана ширина элемента становится больше ширины картинки, а при уменьшении уже картинка не помещается в свой контейнер и сжимается по ширине.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы по высоте картинка занимала все отведенное ей место в контейнере, а по ширине - масштабировалась согласно пропорциям, растягивая соответственно ширину своего родительского контейнера.

```css
html,
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex: 0 1 90%;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.image {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  height: 100%;
  border: black 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image-container {
  flex: 0 1 90%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  flex: 0 1 0%;
}

.text {
  flex: 1 1 10%;
  display: block;
  background: chocolate;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="image">
    <div class="image-container"><img src="https://ru.fishki.net/picsw/012012/05/post/krasota/tn.jpg"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <div class="image-container"><img src="https://learn.javascript.ru/article/box-sizing/border-box@2x.png"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <div class="image-container"><img src="https://learn.javascript.ru/article/box-sizing/border-box@2x.png"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <div class="image-container"><img src="https://learn.javascript.ru/article/box-sizing/border-box@2x.png"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <div class="image-container"><img src="https://learn.javascript.ru/article/box-sizing/border-box@2x.png"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  #gallery_wrapper {
    overflow-x: auto;
  }

  #gallery {
    height: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #gallery .item {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

  #gallery .item img {
    height: calc(100% - 30px);
  }

  #gallery .item .text {
    height: 30px;
    background: orange;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Gallery</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gallery_wrapper">
  <div id="gallery">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/700x1000" alt="">
      <div class="text">700x1000</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300" alt="">
      <div class="text">500x300</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400" alt="">
      <div class="text">200x400</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1500x600" alt="">
      <div class="text">1500x600</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы `img` знал, что ему нельзя вылазить за контейнер, стоит просто указать `max-width: 100%;`.

А дабы контейнер изменялся по размеру картинки, свойство `max-width: 100%;` стоит убрать. **А также все свойства, которые вы ранее прописали внутри блока `image`**

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex: 0 1 90%;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.image {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  height: 100%;
  border: black 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image-container {
  flex: 0 1 90%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.text {
  flex: 1 1 10%;
  display: block;
  background: chocolate;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="image">
    <div class="image-container"><img src="https://ru.fishki.net/picsw/012012/05/post/krasota/tn.jpg"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <div class="image-container"><img src="https://learn.javascript.ru/article/box-sizing/border-box@2x.png"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <div class="image-container"><img src="https://learn.javascript.ru/article/box-sizing/border-box@2x.png"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <div class="image-container"><img src="https://learn.javascript.ru/article/box-sizing/border-box@2x.png"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <div class="image-container"><img src="https://learn.javascript.ru/article/box-sizing/border-box@2x.png"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не совсем то. При задании max-width все элементы слайдера сжимаются по ширине так, чтобы весь слайдер занимал 100% экрана без прокрутки, а изображения внутри деформируются. Мне нужно не чтобы они не вылезали за контейнер, а чтобы контейнер по ширине подстраивался под получившуюся ширину изображения.

Comment: То есть, вы хотите, чтобы тот контейнер, в котором находиться наша картинка, подстраивался под настоящую ширину этой картинки? Верно?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Тогда выходит, что `img` вообще не стоит трогать. Уберите свойство `max-width: 100%;` и просмотрите результат.

Comment: У меня изначально и было без max-width в img. В этом-то и проблема, что ширина контейнера почему-то не подстраивается под изображения.

Comment: @Наталья я изменил код для примера, посмотрите результат. Сейчас картинка растягивает контейнер, под свой размер.

Comment: не растягивает. Посмотрите внимательно - ширина первого контейнера всегда 350px (под исходную ширину картинки) - изображение просто заполняет всю ширину и высоту контейнера, а не увеличивает его.

Comment: **Нужно сделать так, чтобы по высоте картинка занимала все отведенное ей место в контейнере, а по ширине - масштабировалась согласно пропорциям, растягивая соответственно ширину своего родительского контейнера.** - Мы сделали так, чтобы картинка занимала все отведенное ей место в контейнере, и оно растягивает ширину своего родительского контейнера, что оно должна увеличивать? Может быть вы хотите, чтобы картинка например была `350px`, а у родительского контейнера была еще своя минимальная ширина?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/82Q7PXaIjenx6r смотрите, картинка не растягивает свой контейнер по ширине, это видно по тому, как изображения деформировались. Давайте на примере первого контейнера - у него ширина 350 px. Такая ширина стоит потому, что это исходная ширина загруженной в него картинки. Но если мы увеличиваем экран, картинка тоже увеличивается - ее высота вместо исходных 700px становится больше, соответственно если она не будет деформироваться, ее ширина тоже будет пропорционально больше. Но контейнер все еще остается 350px, а нужно чтобы он по ширине становился равен новой ширине изображения

Comment: http://joxi.ru/MAjML5ws4eMQz2 вот еще пример для понимания - здесь выделена картинка и видно, что ее ширина превышает ширину родительского контейнера. Вот мне нужно, чтобы родительский контейнер по ширине расширялся до ширины картинки

Comment: Продемонстрируйте код стилей, в момент скрина экрана, пожалуйста. Вот как у меня отображается: [пример](https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2019/1/20/2b4ab58ddf9bdee9f2f08eb9c60dfab1-full.jpg)

Comment: http://joxi.ru/krD9YQECENNQPm это я для примера убрала display:flex из контейнера изображения, чтобы показать, что если изображение не будет пытаться вписаться по ширине в свой контейнер, то оно будет больше по ширине. Вы и сами должны видеть, что в вашем примере кода изображения деформированы (их ширина сжалась до ширины контейнера) - мне нужно чтобы они не деформировались, а растягивали ширину своих контейнеров соответственно собственной ширине